# How to fix issue with middle vertical liquid boxes

Tags: css, layout, html

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KTmNB/2/

How do I correct this so the middle divs are always in between the top and bottom percentage-based divs, while being able to automatically re-size when the browser does?

I have been reading a lot about liquid layouts, but have been unable to crack this.

Thank-you!

EDIT: I'm also going to have to do this with 8, 10, and 12 divs :s

EDIT: Sort of happy I haven't received a response after 30 minutes, makes me think that it is in fact harder than I thought ^^

Comment: Can't you just, you know, calculate what the position should be? And only use top, left and width, height instead of mixing top,bottom with height and fiddling with margins.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Vh9ZB/

Comment: Do you mind replying so I can approve? =D And thanks!!! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw in your jsfiddle that you are mixing left, top, right and bottom with width and height and top-margin... That may be what caused the confusion, because it's not really that difficult. Just be consistent in choosing how you want to position the things.
E.G. only use, left, top, width and height.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Vh9ZB/

Comment: Makes sense, was over-complicating the problem, thanks a bunch!